# Limit of partial sums

Tags: python, math, sympy, calculus

So I'd like to calculate limit of partial sums, where `a_n` is `sp.Lambda(x, 1/x * sp.factorial2(2*x-1)/sp.factorial2(2*x))`.
I tried this:

```
sp.limit(sp.summation(a(i), (i,1,n)), n, sp.oo)
```

But as I start it, it starts calculating but never ends, so I don't get an answer. Interesting fact is that if I try to calculate infinite sum, I'll get an answer:

```
sp.summation(a(i), (i,1,sp.oo))
>>>2log(2)
```

I can even create a sequence of partial sums:

```
s = sp.SeqFormula(sp.summation(a(i), (i,1,n)), (n, 1, sp.oo))
```

Which, for example in Maple, evaluates the limit kinda. So is there a way to calculate such limit in sympy? Actually I'd like to get an answer similar to summation: `2log(2)`, but using the limit of partial sums.

Answer (score 0):

```
def limsum(it, epsilon):
    ret = 0
    x = next(it)
    while x<epsilon:
        ret = ret + x
        x = next(it)
    return ret
```

Comment: Add some explanation perhaps?

Comment: There is a difference between an approximation of a limit and the limit itself. At best, your answer (after you fix the bug in the direction of the inequality (`x<epsilon` should be `x > epsilon`) gives an approximation to within a given tolerance. At worst, it doesn't even do that. It simply isn't true that the error at stopping with a given term is bounded by the size of that term. It is (almost) true for alternating series but can be off dramatically for other series. This doesn't answer the question that OP asks, and doesn't answer very well a question that OP doesn't ask.